# How to find the most recent file containing a particular text in Unix?

Tags: unix, grep, find

I've a directory with thousands of files, many of them containing the text I'm looking for. I've to search only in a single directory. I need to find the most recently created file in the directory that contains a particular text, say "check".

I've tried grep, find and ls, but I can either find a list of files containing the text e.g.

```
 find . -type f -exec grep -l check {} +
```

or, the latest file in a directory using:

```
ls -t1 |  head -n 1
```

How can I combine both to get the latest file containing a particular text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tweeked my initial command to get the desired results. I'm posting here for future searches:

```
find . -type f | xargs grep -l "text to find" | xargs ls -rt | tail -1
```

Comment: You don't need `find`.  You could just use grep.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple way to do this:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -l check {} + | xargs ls -latr
```

Comment: Gives me an error for grep `grep: illegal option -- r`

Comment: Wired, try to use whit "R" uppercase

Comment: Thanks for the help, I tweeked my find, grep and ls to get the filename.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a decent way to do it:

```bash
grep -Pl '<PATTERN>' <DIR> -R \
  | xargs stat \
  | grep '(Change:|File:)' -P \
  | sed -r 's/^\s*//; s/File:.*\s(.*)`/\1/; '"s/'$//;"'s/Change:(.*)$/\1*/' \
  | tr -d '\n' \
  | tr '*' '\n' \
  | awk '{printf "%s %s %s\n", $3, $2, $1; }' \
  | sort -unr
```

Where `<PATTERN>` is the text you want to find and `<DIR>` is the path you want to look in.

#### Step-by-Step

1. **Grep**

   - `-R` search recursively *and* follow symlinks.
   - `-P` `PATTERN` can be a perl regexp.
   - `-l` only print the names of files containing a match
2. **Xargs**

   - xargs will run `stat` against each line of input coming from `STDIN`, which is the output from grep.
3. **Grep**

   - `-P` allow perl regexp in `PATTERN`.

   1. `'(Change:|File:)'`
      We only want the filename and modification time from `stat`.
4. **Sed**

   - `-r` enables support for extended regular expressions

   1. `s/^\s*//`
      Deletes all whitespace from the start of each line.
   2. ```
      s/File:.*\s(.*)/\1/
      ```

      Replace `File:`, any immediate whitespace, and ` with the contents of group 1 `(.*)`
   3. `s/'$//`
      Delete the single-quote from lines ending with one.
   4. ```
      s/Change:(.*)$/\1*/
      ```

      Delete `Change:` and add a `*`<sup>†</sup> at the end of each line.
5. **Tr**

   - `-d` delete the character instead of replacing it.

   1. `'\n'`
      Delete newlines
   2. `'*' '\n'`
      Replace asterisks with newlines.
6. **Awk**

   1. Print output like so `HH:MM:SS.MS DATE FILE`
7. **Sort**

   - `-u` discard duplicate lines
     We only want each file to appear once--we don't care how many times the pattern has appeared in the files.
   - `-n` compare according to string numerical value
     We're comparing timestamps.
   - `-r` reverse the result of comparisons    
     So the most recent file is at the top instead.

<sup>†</sup> I use `*` here because none of the files in my use-case had an asterisk in their name.  You can use whatever character you like, so long as it doesn't appear in any of the filenames or in the output from `stat`.

Answer (score 0):

May be a late response, hope this helps someone later.

I am not a pro in Shell, but found below one works for me and this is very simple to use and understand.

```
grep '<Search String>' $(ls -t1 |  head -n 1)
```